# PHP - can I rewrite just the close() method of the session handler?

Tags: php, session, url-rewriting, handler

I'm trying to log the access of users in a web application. When they log in, they get enrolled into a table called `users_access`, where the `session_start` field is filled with the time when the user logs out. The same goes for the `session_end` field, where I fill it when the user logs out. But what if the user session expires?

I know I can write my own session handler, but I was wondering if you can just rewrite the `close()` method to automatically fill the `session_end` field once the user reaches the session timeout.

I would like to do this because I dont't want to alter the default behavior of the session handler, just the method I need.

Is it possible?

Comment: I've never done this, but I imagine you can extend the `SessionHandler` class and just override the `close` method...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php  yeah. extend the default session class, and provide that class to [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)